# Clion how to add files to a project

Tags: cmake, clion

This seems really basic. How can i add files to a project without having to manually edit the `CMakeLists.txt`.

For example source files in another directory

Comment: Yes, the question relates to limitations with clion not with cmake

Answer (score 8):

CLion parses the `CMakeLists.txt` and uses it to generate a project view, but I believe the only way to add files to the project is to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` to include those files.  I expect that eventually this will change similar to the way IntelliJ integrates with a `pom.xml` file in a Java project, but for now you edit the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: +1 You really don't want clion editing your `CMakeLists.txt`. You can look into `file(GLOB ...)` and `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` to automatically find newly added source. But you'll have to force CMake to be re-run in order for them to be added.

Comment: @kmac I'm not a fan of the `GLOB` approach, particularly if you have platform specific sources and you want to conditionally add them to the project.  For simple projects, it's fine, but I prefer adding the files explicitly.

Comment: Yes, this tends to be a hotly debated subject. I think that it is a very useful tool, though not always appropriate. Even in complex projects, if components are broken down into smaller libraries (or even source sub-folders), GLOB can still work well if used judiciously. We're happily working away like this on a project with 400k+ lines of code -- no regrets :).

Answer (score 5):

There is also a way to make CLion to add any cpp and h files (I don't know why don't they do it by default) and is to add this line:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
    *.h
    *.cpp
)
```

and also edit the line of:

```
add_executable(ClionProject ${SOURCE_FILES} ${SOURCES})
```

In this example: ClionProject is actually the name of the project. SOURCES_FILES and SOURCES can be whatever you want.

Another good idea is to go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake and tick on "Automatic reload CMake project on editing"

Here is a good starting tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/quick-cmake-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

No other option. You have to edit the `CMakeLists.txt`. CLion is completely cmake based IDE. Even if you need to link external libraries, you need to edit the above-mentioned file. It doesn't work like in GUI based code-blocks for example.

Answer (score -1):

How about right clicking the `CMakeLists.txt` editor tab, clicking "Open in -> terminal", typing `ls` or `find` or whatnot, and copy-and-pasting from there?